# Highlight Multiple Dates on thirdparty React Datepicker Component

Tags: reactjs, datepicker

in my company there was a react library which has datepicker component but this datepicker doesnt have any option or support for highlighting multiple dates (not continously) . I am using this component for my datepicker  functionality, now i need to look for a workaround or code that  can make the datepicker so that when i click on datepicker calendar icon.it should shows some dates with highlighted based on the server response data which is already available